# Force form submission with invalid field

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc

Can I force a form with an invalid text field to submit? or can I force the invalid field to be valid so that I can submit the form?

I have a form with 2 submit buttons. One that is disabled and will be enabled for submission if a remote call is made and the proper value is entered (4 digit pass code). The second button should submit the form bypassing the pass code field. I'm giving the user the option to opt out of entering in a pass code value, so I want to be able to submit the form even if the pass code field is invalid, but I can't figure out how to do it! I've tried in javascript/Jquery to reset validation and reset the form but nothing seems to be working. I can make an Ajax call when the button is pressed but I'd prefer to use the forms post call.

Can I force a form submission with invalid fields or can I set the form to valid? I have both html data attributes for the field and data attributes in the view model in C#. I guess all would need to be disabled or by-passed to submit!
I've read the HTML attributes can be reset or removed with JQuery validate calls, which I'm trying below in my sample JS code, but what about the view model attributes in c#?

Here is a [Net Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/x4ZT5J) I've been working on to show. The code below is just a copy and paste from the fiddle and the javascript is just an example of what I've tried to reset/clear the invalid field

```js
$("#finish").off('click').on('click', function() {
  $("#Finish").val(true);
  $("#RatingValueHidden").val($("#hostRating").val());


  //$("#rateForm").validate().resetForm();
  //$("#PointCode").val("0000");

  //$("#PointCode").rules("add", {
  //    required: false,
  //    minlength: 0,
  //    maxlength: 0
  //});

  //var validator = $("#rateForm").validate();

  //$("#rateForm").data("validator").resetForm()

  //var isValid = $("#rateForm").valid();
  //validator.resetForm();
  //$("#rateForm").submit();

  

});
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Bootstrap 101 Template</title>

  <!-- CSS Includes -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

  <style type="text/css">
    .field-validation-error {
      color: #ff0000;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
      <h1>Enter 4 digit code</h1>

      @using (Html.BeginForm()) {
      <div class="form-group">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.PointCode, new { @class = "form-control input-lg", @placeholder = "4 Digit Code", @maxlength = "4", @type = "number", @min = "1000", @max = "9999", @title = "Your point code is a 4 digit number" }) @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model
        => model.PointCode)
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <div style="margin: auto; margin-bottom: 20px;">
          <button id="finish" class="btn-yb btn btn-default btn-lg btn-block" type="submit">No Thanks, I'm done</button>
        </div>


        <div style="margin: auto;">
          <button id="rateReview" class="btn-yb btn btn-default btn-lg btn-block" type="submit" disabled>Rate and Review</button>
        </div>
      </div>


      }

      <br/><br/>
      <div class="alert alert-warning fade">
        <img src="http://entechprod.blob.core.windows.net/dotnetfiddle/morpheus.jpg" style="max-width:100%;" /><br/><br/>
        <strong><span class="alert-content"></span></strong>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


</body>

</html>
```

In my view model I have this field for a remote call

```
    [MinLength(4, ErrorMessage = "Your point code is a 4 digit number")]
    [MaxLength(4)]
    [Remote("IsPointCodeCorrect", "Rate", HttpMethod = "Get", ErrorMessage = "The point code entered is incorrect", AdditionalFields = "EventId")]
    public int? PointCode { get; set; }
```

and the text field I have looks like this

```
<div id="inputGroupPointCode" class="input-group textbox-style" style="width: 100%;">
  @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.PointCode, new { @class = "form-control input-lg", @placeholder = "4 Digit Code", @maxlength = "4", @type = "number", @min = "1000", @max = "9999", @title = "Your point code is a 4 digit number" })
</div>
```

Comment: It's working...I added a message in order to test the behaviour....your code is correct https://dotnetfiddle.net/lqpwTD

Comment: Hackeman, thanks for the help, but I want the form to submit if the form has an invalid field. So if I try and put in a '12' into the field, then press the button I want the form to submit, but it's not, it just shows the invalid field error message and has an invalid state. I want to force that state to valid somehow or submit the form with an invalid state somehow, I don't care which way just that it submits

Comment: In that case just remove the validation...in that escenario is pointless

Comment: yes ok, but how would I remove the validation from both the html and view model? so that I can submit?

Comment: Like this https://dotnetfiddle.net/lqpwTD

Comment: that's not quite what I meant, just removing the data attributes and the remote call from the view model doesn't solve the issue. I still need validation in that field when the user wants to enter in a pass code value.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer I was looking for

```
<input formnovalidate="formnovalidate">
```

found at

[link](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_formnovalidate.asp)